# (intent.getStringExtra("PaymentDetails") is null

Tags: android, json, paypal

I added PayPal SDK to the my application, but I have got a one problem.
When I want to view a details of payment, the app will crash.

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

 public class PaymentDeatils extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_deatils);

    //Getting Intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    try {
         JSONObject jsonDetails = new 
    JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("PaymentDetails"));
         showDetails(jsonDetails.getJSONObject("response"), 
    intent.getStringExtra("PaymentAmount"));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void showDetails(JSONObject jsonDetails, String paymentAmount) 
throws JSONException {
    //Views
    TextView txtId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtId);
    TextView textViewStatus= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAnount);
    TextView txtStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

    //Showing the details from json object
    txtId .setText(jsonDetails.getString("id"));
    textViewStatus.setText(jsonDetails.getString("state"));
    txtStatus.setText(paymentAmount);
}
}
```

I have got problem here

```
   JSONObject jsonDetails = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("PaymentDetails"));
```

intent.getStringExtra("PaymentDetails") probably is null. How i can fix it?

Error in console.

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int 
  java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: paste your code where you are sending intent from as well

Comment: If you are in this state, I suppose you already got success response from Paypal on previous activity's onActivityResult. The problem is `intent.getStringExtra("PaymentDetails")` result to null. Check if the key, **PaymentDetails** is right(no typo). Also check if you already call `intent.putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails)` from the previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

As Abdul said, we need to see the sending activity as well. In addition, getIntent.getStringExtra also supports setting a default value after the key, that will at least reduce the likely hood of a null exception crash.